# jpos/res/jpos.properties file not found

Tags: java, printers, thermal-printer, epson, javapos

I have a problem with javapos. When I try code sample program for print "Hello JavaPOS" from printer Epson TM-T20

```
POSPrinterControl113 ptr = (POSPrinterControl113)new POSPrinter();

JPanel contentPane;
JPanel jPanel_reciept = new JPanel();
TitledBorder titledBorder1;
GridBagLayout gridBagLayout1 = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagLayout gridBagLayout2 = new GridBagLayout();
JButton jButton_Print = new JButton();

/**Constract "Frame"*/
public Step1Frame() {
    enableEvents(AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK);
    try {
        jbInit();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**Form the component*/
private void jbInit() throws Exception  {
    //setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(Step1Frame.class.getResource("[Your Icon]")));
    contentPane = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
    titledBorder1 = new TitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white,new Color(134, 134, 134)),"Receipt");
    contentPane.setLayout(gridBagLayout1);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(300, 180));
    this.setTitle("Step 1  Print \"Hello JavaPOS\"");
    jPanel_reciept.setLayout(gridBagLayout2);
    jPanel_reciept.setBorder(titledBorder1);
    jButton_Print.setText("Print");
    jButton_Print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jButton_Print_actionPerformed(e);
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(jPanel_reciept, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0
            ,GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(15, 0, 0, 0), 20, 20));
    jPanel_reciept.add(jButton_Print, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0
            ,GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10), 130, 0));
}

/**
 * Outline     The processing code required in order to enable
 *            or to disable use of service is written here.
 * @exception JposException  This exception is fired toward the failure of
 *                          the method which JavaPOS defines.
 */
/**When the window was closed*/
protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e) {
    super.processWindowEvent(e);
    if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
        this.closing();
    }
    /**When the window open*/
    else if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_OPENED) {
        // JavaPOS's code for Step1
        try {
            //Open the device.
            //Use the name of the device that connected with your computer.
            ptr.open("POSPrinter");

            //Get the exclusive control right for the opened device.
            //Then the device is disable from other application.
            ptr.claim(1000);

            //Enable the device.
            ptr.setDeviceEnabled(true);
        }
        catch(JposException ex) {
        }
    }
    // JavaPOS's code for Step1--END
}

//***********************Button*************************************************
/**
 * Outline      The code for using the most standard method "PrintNormal"
 *             to print is described.
 */
void jButton_Print_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // JavaPOS's code for Step1
    try{
        //printNormal(int station, String data)
        //A string is sent by using the method "printNormal", and it is printed.
        // "\n" is the standard code for starting a new line.
        // When the end of the line have no "\n",printing by
        //  using the method "printNormal" doesn't start, may be.
        ptr.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,"Hello JavaPOS\n");
    }
    catch(JposException ex){
    }
    // JavaPOS's code for Step1--END
}

//***********************Method*************************************************
/**
 * Outline     The code to finish a service.
 */
void closing(){
    // JavaPOS's code for Step1
    try{
        //Cancel the device.
        ptr.setDeviceEnabled(false);

        //Release the device exclusive control right.
        ptr.release();

        //Finish using the device.
        ptr.close();
    }
    catch(JposException ex){
    }
    // JavaPOS's code for Step1--END
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Show me in output 3x jpos/res/jpos.properties file not found

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: The JavaPOS library will look in your classpath for jpos/res/jpos.properties and then for jpos.xml. Did you try to generate these files with the help of Epson setup program? On windows it should be C:\Program Files\EPSON\JavaPOS\SetupPOS\SetupPOS.exe.

Comment: Do you have a correct setup? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839049/how-can-i-use-javapos-to-print-reciepts-with-an-epson-printer/30839050#30839050

Answer (score 0):

I nowhere found correct answer for this very old question
if you get

```
jpos/res/jpos.properties file not found
```

you have 2 ways:

1. ignore this error and set properties from the code

   ```
    System.setProperty("jpos.config.populatorFile", "jposxml.cfg");  
    System.setProperty("jpos.util.tracing.TurnOnNamedTracers", "JposServiceLoader,SimpleEntryRegistry,SimpleRegPopulator,XercesRegPopulator");  
    System.setProperty("jpos.util.tracing.TurnOnAllNamedTracers", "ON"); 
    System.setProperty("jpos.loader.serviceManagerClass", "jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceManager")
   ```
2. extract you jposXXX.jar(usually XXX means version),
   add jpos.properties and jpos.xml files to the folder jposXXX/jpos/res/,
   convert folder jposXXX to jar file
   for example via command in terminal`jar cvf jposXXX.jar jposXXX`
   put jar file to app/libs/ folder
   add to your gradle dependencies line

   `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`
   enjoy